# Como desactivar el "corriendo en tu red local" en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Junto con saludarles les comento que estoy realizando un proyecto personal en react, pero al momento de ejecutar el comando npm start me di cuenta que luego aparece un problema, y ese problema es que el proyecto también se está ejecutando en red local, por lo que cualquiera podría verlo lo cual no es mi idea al menos aun, adjunto foto de lo comentado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien tiene algúna idea de como poder desactivar esa opción o bloquear las conexiones externas que entren? la idea es que mi proyecto sea lo más privado posible hasta publicarlo, cualquer información la agradecería

Comment: Hay alguien mas conectado a esa red??? Alguien mas sabe que lo estas ejecutando? alguien esta atacando tu pc? esa red es interna... de afuera, nadie va a poder entrar...

Comment: Hola!, Si, en la red que lo ejecuto hay varias personas, y no, nadie sabe que lo estoy ejecutando en la red, la red es interna, pero me gustaría evitar que incluso los usuarios de la misma red no tuvieran acceso hasta que yo se los permita

Comment: desconecta tu pc de la red... podrias poner un firewall.. la verdad la pregunta no tiene mucho sentido.. si nadie sabe el puerto, nadie va a poder entrar...

Comment: lo que me da miedo es que pudiera entrar alguien externo y poder entrar colocando la ip:3000 que se que se puede ver desde otro equipo solo colocando esa ip, lo desconectaría del internet pero lo uso para el mismo desarrollo

Comment: no existe externo, porque esa ip no es publica a internet, es de tu red... si no, basicamente, todos, pero todos, tendriamos el mismo problema...

Answer (score 1):

Hola espero y esto te ayude, entrando a Firewal>Reglas de entrada>Node.js: Server-side JavaScript. Doble click y bloqueas la conexión, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola @Pablo Lucas voy a problarlo y vuelvo con respuesta, muchas gracias por la idea!

Comment: no, no resultó esto

Answer (score 1):

La forma más fácil es configurando la varialbe de entorno `HOST` al llamar a `npm start`. Hay dos formas:

1. en lugar de llamar `npm start`, llama a `HOST=localhost npm start`
2. modifica el script de `start` dentro del archivo *package.json*:

```
{
    "start": "react-scripts start"
}
```

cambia por

```
{
    "start": "HOST=localhost react-scripts start"
}
```

Comment: Hola, intenté ese comando en el start en el archivo package.json pero me arroja un error: "HOST" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos los que aportaron a mi pregunta, luego pensar y analizar la estructura de como se ejecutan los scripts de react, ubiqué el archivo de ejecución de scripts ubicado en node_modules/react-scripts/start:

En ese archivo se traen los componentes que ejecutan react y todas sus herramientas, en la línea 56 de ese archivo se define el host que está escrito de la siguiente forma:

```
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
```

y todo lo que había que hacer era cambiar eso a lo que voy a colocar a continuación:

```
const HOST = 'localhost'
```

y el resultado fue el esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a todos quienes intentaron ayudar, si esta pregunta y su respuesta le sirven a alguien más sería excelente

Comment: la razón detrás es que la opción predeterminada [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) significa "en todas las interfaces disponibles" lo cual incluye `localhost` y todas las otras interfaces de la red interna/externa

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: cuando vuelvas a instalar o al hacer un upgrade, vas a perder esa configuracion.

Comment: @aloMalbarez, me interesa de momento que solo funcione en localhost, y en ninguna otra ubicación en la red

Comment: @eventHandler lo tengo presente, no creo que me moleste o duela hacer esa modificación de vez en cuando sea necesario

Comment: fijate que `const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';` significa :  si `process.env.HOST` no esta definido entonces usar `0.0.0.0` es decir que con setear una variable de sistema/entorno llamada HOST ya debería funcionar como requeris, onda `export HOST=localhost && npm start` o ya ponerla system wide `sudo -H nano /etc/environment`